# Mysql procedure updating wrong value due to multi-threading in Java

Tags: mysql, multithreading, stored-procedures

I am using below mentioned MYSQL procedure(exact arguments not mentioned) to insert the data in three tables 
"T1" ,"T2" and "T3".

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `insert_values`(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6.......)
begin
declare max_id bigint;
start transaction;
insert ignore into T1
fields(.....)
values
(v1,v2,v3,.......);
insert ignore into T2
fields(......)
values
(v1,v4,..........);
If (v3 <> '') Then
    set @max_id:=(select max(id) from T1); 
    insert ignore into T3
    fields(.......)
    values
    (@max_id,v3,v5,v6,........);
End If;
commit;
end
```

In table T1 and T2 the field "id" is the primary key which is auto-increment so not getting inserted through procedure. 
In this procedure I am inserting data first in table T1 and T2 and then reading the maximum "id" 
(last inserted/auto-incremented "id") from table T1 in variable "max_id" which was auto-generated 
by "insert ignore into T1....." query of this procedure.

I am calling this procedure through java code which is using multi-threading.

My problem is that the statement "set @max_id:=(select max(id) from T1);" is sometimes instead of reading the last 
auto-increment value generated by "insert ignore into T1....." query of this session/thread, is reading the wrong 
value(because may be  another parallel thread is inserting its data in the table T1 before the current thread reads 
the "max_id" from T1 and hence "max_id" is getting the value incremented by another thread).

So how to resolve this issue?
Is changing the isolation level can be the solution?

These tables using INNODB storage engine.

"@@GLOBAL.tx_isolation" is 'REPEATABLE-READ'

"@@tx_isolation" is 'REPEATABLE-READ'

"@@autocommit" is '1'

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)?

```sql
...
insert ignore into T1
fields(.....)
values
(v1,v2,v3,.......);
/* SET @max_id := LAST_INSERT_ID(); */
SET max_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
...
insert ignore into T3
fields(.......)
values
(max_id,v3,v5,v6,........);
...
```

**UPDATE**

It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) (@max_id) and [13.6.4.1. Local Variable Syntax DECLARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html) (max_id), are different variables. In this case better to use (max_id) local variable.

Comment: Thanks @wchiquito !! I had changed the code of procedure as per your suggestion and observing its working for past 3 days continuously. Till now the problem has not repeated. So I feel the problem is resolved now. But still I didn't understand how these changes have resolved it..